# how to join words by _ if condition is satisfied

Tags: bash, shell

Good day,

I was wondering how to join words if among them are only one single space

Example

```
this not work
this work
```

To obtain

```
this not work
this_work
```

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NF==2{sub(/ /,"_")}1' file
this not work
this_work
```

- Check for lines with two words.
- If such line is found, substitute the space with `_`.

Comment: Now it works if there is no more spaces at the end or at the beginning of the two words. Thanks

Comment: @Alejandro You didn't specify that as your input data but for leading or trailing spaces you can change the answer to        `awk 'NF==2{$1=$1;sub(/ /,"_")}1' file`